# Rendering an image onto a JPanel's backwards compatibility issues--what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, swing

I've been working on a Battleship game for a school assignment in Eclipse using the latest version of java, Java 6, until I realized that I need to provide compatibility for the 1.4.2 JRE.

I've been careful to not use any features and library classes that are not available in the 1.4.2 compiler, and my code compiles fine. The problem is that the background image for the game is not rendering properly--only a small corner in the top left is being rendered.

For reference, here are screenshots showing my problem:

The game rendering properly under the Java 6 runtime environment

[Image Link (I can't embed them yet.)](http://i237.photobucket.com/albums/ff38/geoffxy/filledscreen.jpg)

Only the corner being rendered under the 1.4.2 JRE

[Image Link (I can't embed them yet.)](http://i237.photobucket.com/albums/ff38/geoffxy/blankscreen.jpg)

And, of course, there is no difference in the code in the two screenshots, just different runtime environments.

The background is being drawn on a JPanel that is visible, and added to the JFrame using `setContentPane()`. There are no errors with loading the image into the program.

I've done a lot of testing and noticed that my input handler is only responding to input within that small corner that has an image in it, which would mean that my JPanel is not filling the whole screen--however I've double checked its size and it matches the JFrame's size (800 x 600).

And here's my rendering code:

```
public void render() {                               

        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();
        Graphics2D gb = (Graphics2D) buffer.getGraphics();

        gb.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);

        gb.setColor(new Color(45, 45, 45));
        gb.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
        gb.drawString("Outwit the computer. Are you up for the challenge?", 175, 185);

        cont.draw(gb, contState);

        //Draw buffer to screen
        g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, null);

}
```

This method is called repeatedly to render the game's frames. It is part of a JPanel class.

I've tried nearly everything, and this is my last resort. Could this perhaps be a bug with the older runtime environment? Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks so much in advance. :)

Comment: Its hard to tell what you are doing without the full context of how you do the painting. For example custom painting should be done in the paintComponent() method of your JPanel using the Graphics object that is passed to the method. You should not use the getGraphics() method to get a Graphics object unless you are getting the Graphics object of a BufferedImage and then painting on the buffered image. You need to post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem. I don't use JDK1.4.2, but maybe I can notice other painting problems.

Comment: I just gave paintComponent() a try and there's still no difference, the small corner is still only being painted again... Also, thanks for the info on getGraphics(), I'll be sure to take that into account into my code. :)

I'll work on getting a SSCCE posted.

Comment: @Geoff: you've "given it a try" but that tells us nothing about just what you've done or why the new code doesn't work. I second camickr's recommendation: create and provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org) to let us see and test what you're doing.